# Proper soft starter for vacuum cleaner universal motor

Tags: current, universal-motor

According to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449466/max-startup-current-for-vacuum-cleaner-motor) question:

[Max startup current for vacuum cleaner motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/449466/max-startup-current-for-vacuum-cleaner-motor)

We have the problem of tripping the dental clinic circuit breakers during the starting the universal motor.

I am trying to test one proper soft starter for the [vacuum cleaner universal motor 2200W 220v](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fi%2F32890863363.html), so [by googling](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03-o_eP1BgNz6vK6ENCUWPHMCnDIw:1598179178406&q=soft%20start%20universal%20machine&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR_NyxkbHrAhUQ2KQKHe4nAfUQBSgAegQIMxAp&biw=1866&bih=1051) find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igb9FntUCck):

[image]

I tried to update it for 2200W 220v Universal motor, by this calculation:

> According to the above universal motor use almost 2200w/220v=10A RMS and based of its ratio to [the universal drill motor current which is around 6A RMS](https://www.220-electronics.com/220-volt-drill.html) could be updated for my usage by adding one 12R 5W high power resistor  (3x12R 5w).

Is this soft starter good for my problem, and if not what is the proper soft starter to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better to make something more hi-tech if you intend to make a PCB board abd embed into a machine.

Today these motor controller are made with tinny MCUs, but some decades ago they were made from specific IC made from Telefunken, Temic, Siemens, lastly from Atmel. The [U2008B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/36/doc4712-29429.pdf) would solve your demand. Probably you can still get some ready made board with potentiometer to adjust speed, Google is your friend.

EDIT:

If your motor is equiped with tacho (speed sensor), then there are also bunch of TDA1085C boards lying arround.